# How to extract sentences matching 2 words in HTML document that may not have a period

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple URLs here that I need to extract sentences with words: `live` (variants) and `work`. 
(with examples of almost working formula and ideal result -- I'm having problems with rows 4, 5,& 6)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dLJfaFA_-XuVlPmS0VN0d8IR4nkUsXpCxpUwZvgLXx4/edit#gid=0

I was able to extract most but not all with regex, 
Here's my regex matching formula:

`[^.>""]*[Ll]iv(e |es|e,|ing).* work.*(?=(<|\.|!|&))`

I can use this matching formula:

`>.*[Ll]iv(e |es|e,|ing).* work.*<`

However, it cuts off sentences and doesn't match other html documents.

Would love to get a matching formula that works on all URLs. I've been working for days on this and could not find the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the formula: 
`(>|"")[^<>""]*[Ll]iv(e |es|e,|ing).* work.*(?=(<|\.|!|&))`

Then filter out unwanted characters from there